# Two factor ANOVA with blocking

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design

I am conducting an RCBD experiment in which I have Treatment A (with 5 levels) and Treatment B (two levels). It is also being done in 3 separate locations (3 blocks). My question is, how can I do the ANOVA? Do I just treat it like a three-way ANOVA? And how should I code it in R?

Comment: You have three categorical variables and all of the (three-way) interactions, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add block as an extra (factorial) covariate to the linear model.

Simple R code (presuming the DV is a continous variable):

```
anova(model<-lm(DV~block+A*B,data=mydata))
```

You might also want to do post-hoc tests. The emmeans package in R is pretty good for this.

```
library(emmeans)
emmeans(model,pairwise~A|B)
```

The A|B can be replaced with one of B|A or A:B, which will all answer slightly different questions, and of course just A or B (drop the interaction from the model first before doing these though).

Comment: thank you very much!